# Hide navigation bar while login in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, react-router, navigation, react-router-dom

Is there better way to hide navigation while on the `"/login"` path?

I have made a react hook which is set to true when login component renders.

```
<BrowserRouter>
    {!isLogin?
        <MainNavbar user={User?User:undefined}/>:null
    }
    <Routes>
                        
        <Route path='/' element={<HomeComponent />}> </Route>
                        
        <Route path='/login'  element={<UserLogin setlogin={setlogin} setUser={setUser}/>}> </Route>

        <Route  path='/signup' element={<Userlog setlogin={setlogin} setUser={setUser}/>} />

        {/* <Route exact path='/signup'  element={<SignUp setlogin={setlogin} setUser={setUser}/>}> </Route> */}

        <Route  path='/aboutus' element={<AboutUs />}></Route>
                        
        <Route  path='/contactus' element={<ContactUs />}></Route>

        <Route  path='/colleges' element={<CollegeList />} ></Route>
                        
        {Colleges && <>
                        
            <Route exact path='/college' element={<CollegeNavBar user={User?User:undefined} college={Colleges?Colleges[0]:undefined}/>} >

            <Route exact path='/college/collegehome' element={<College user={User?User:undefined} college={Colleges?Colleges[0]:undefined}/>} />
                            
            <Route exact path='/college/about' element={<CollegeAboutUs 
                id={Colleges[0]._id} 
                />} > </Route>
                            
            <Route exact path='/college/posts' element={<PostList 
                collegeId={Colleges[0]._id} logo={Colleges[0].logo} city={Colleges[0].city}
                name={Colleges[0].name} posts={Colleges[0].posts}  User={User?User._id:undefined} />}></Route>
                            
            <Route exact path='/college/notices' element={<NoticeList
                collegeId={Colleges[0]._id} notices={Colleges[0].notices} />}></Route>
                            
            <Route exact path='/college/contact' element={<CollegeContactus 
            />}></Route>

            </Route>
        </>}
        <Route exact path='/collegehome/search' element={<Search />}></Route>
                        
    </Routes>
</BrowserRouter>
```

I have also tried calling `MainNavbar` after the route of the login but it gives an error.

Answer (score 0):

You can use layout routes to conditionally render additional UI components. Layout components render any content and an `Outlet` for nested `Route` components to be rendered into. Here you aren't conditionally hiding the navbar for a specific route, you are unconditionally rendering it for all routes rendered by the layout route.

Example:

```
import { Navigate, Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';

const NavLayout = () => (
  <>
    <MainNavbar user={User?User:undefined}/>
    <Outlet />
  </>
);

const CollegeLayout = ({ showCollege }) => showCollege
  ? <Outlet />
  : <Navigate to="/" replace />;
```

...

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <Routes>
    <Route
      path='/login'
      element={<UserLogin setlogin={setlogin} setUser={setUser} />}
    />

    <Route element={<NavLayout />}>
      <Route path='/' element={<HomeComponent />} />
      <Route
        path='/signup'
        element={<Userlog setlogin={setlogin} setUser={setUser} />}
      />
      <Route path='/aboutus' element={<AboutUs />} />
      <Route path='/contactus' element={<ContactUs />} />
      <Route path='/colleges' element={<CollegeList />} />
      <Route path='/college' element={<CollegeLayout showCollege={College} />}>
        <Route
          index
          element={(
            <CollegeNavBar
              user={User?User:undefined}
              college={Colleges?Colleges[0]:undefined}
            />
          )}
        />
        <Route
          path='collegehome'
          element={(
            <College
              user={User?User:undefined}
              college={Colleges?Colleges[0]:undefined}
            />
          )}
        />            
        <Route
          path='about'
          element={<CollegeAboutUs id={Colleges[0]._id} />}
        />            
        <Route
          path='posts'
          element={(
            <PostList
              collegeId={Colleges[0]._id}
              logo={Colleges[0].logo}
              city={Colleges[0].city}
              name={Colleges[0].name}
              posts={Colleges[0].posts}
              User={User?User._id:undefined}
            />
          )}
        />            
        <Route
          path='notices'
          element={(
            <NoticeList
              collegeId={Colleges[0]._id}
              notices={Colleges[0].notices}
            />
          )}
        />            
        <Route
          path='/college/contact'
          element={<CollegeContactus />}
        />        
      </Route>
      <Route path='/collegehome/search' element={<Search />} />
    </Route>
  </Routes>
</BrowserRouter>
```